# How to add custom js form validation with custom error message in magento2?

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation

I am trying to do a custom js validation for a form field, I added this in my phtml file :

```
var theForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
Validation.add('validate-testx','You failed to enter baz!',function(v){
if(v == 'baz')
{
return true;
}
return false;
});
```

and added

**validate-testx**

to the filed's css class but it did not work. I am using magento 2, please help.

Comment: I achieved it using the following:
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){
$.validator.addMethod(
'validate-member-card', function (value) {
return (value.length === 16 && /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value)); // Validation logic here
}, $.mage.__('Not a valid Membership ID'));

});
</script>
Worked fine..

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a to add a custom rule with custom error message, I achieved it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){
$.validator.addMethod(
'validate-member-card', function (value) {
return (value.length === 16 && /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value)); // Validation logic here
}, $.mage.__('Not a valid Membership ID'));

});
</script>
```

Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

without `.js` you can do like this for better practice.

```
<form action="<?php  echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'frontneme/index/action';?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">

<div class="field required">
            <label for="order_id" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Id') ?></span><span class="span">*</span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="order_id" value="" autocomplete="off" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Id') ?>" class="input-text " id="order_id" data-validate="{required:true}">
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

when submit the form magento2 automatically showing it is mandatory like client side validation same as `javascript`.

Comment: No I wanted a to add a custom rule with custom error message,I achieved it using:
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){
$.validator.addMethod(
'validate-member-card', function (value) {
return (value.length === 16 && /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value)); // Validation logic here
}, $.mage.__('Not a valid Membership ID'));

});
</script>
Worked fine.. thanks for the reply